# Unable to post to Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to set my WP site up so that when I publish a post, it is sent to a Facebook Page. Unfortunatly I cannot get this to work. The code below is being included, but just seems to be doing nothing (presumably FB is sending back an error, but WP is not displaying it).

When I try to visit the feed for the Page I wish to post on (below), I'm told that I do not have the correct permissions (also below)

> https://graph.facebook.com/163797013684290/feed

```
/** The error I recieve when visiting the above page */
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

I've so far completed these setps -

1. Visit to the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Select the App that I wish to post to my Page from the dropdown menu
3. Clicked 'Get Access Token'
4. Selected the 'manage_pages' permission
5. Re-signed in, granting permission for the App to access my Pages
6. Created the followin script, incorporating the Access Token that has been generated.

Please can someone help, as I have no idea where to go from here. Thanks.

---

```
class Publish_To_Facebook{

    /**
     * The ID of the Page to edit
     *
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    private $page_id = '163797013684290';   

    /**
     * The Page access token given to the application set up to post to the Page
     *
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    private $page_access_token = 'my_access_token'; 

    /**
     * The back-end service for Page's wall
     *
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    private $post_url = '';

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __constructor(){

        $this->post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed';

    }

    /**
     * Manages the POST message to post an update on a page wall
     * 
     * @param array $data
     * @return string the back-end response
     */
    public function message($data){

        /** Grab the $page_access_token */
        $data['access_token'] = $this->page_access_token;

        /** Initiate CURL */
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->post_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        /** Execute and close CURL */
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $return;

    }
}

$to_post = array(
    'message'     => 'The status header', 
    'link'        => 'http://theurltopoint.to', 
    'picture'     => 'http://thepicturetoinclude.jpg',
    'name'        => 'Name of the picture, shown just above it', 
    'description' => 'Full description explaining whether the header or the picture'
);
$facebook = new Publish_To_Facebook();
$facebook->message($to_post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at this page to fix it. It describes the full process.

[Login as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/)

Here is some info from the documentation regarding the Page access token:

> Page Access Tokens
>
> To perform the following operations as a Page, and not the current user, you must use the Page's access token, not the user access token commonly used for reading Graph API objects. This access token can be retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the manage_pages permission. This will return a list of Pages (including application profile Pages) to which the user has administrative access, along with access_tokens for those Pages. Alternatively, you can get a page access token for a single, specific, page by issuing an HTTP GET to /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages permission, as described above. Publishing to a Page also requires the publish_stream permission, unless otherwise noted.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens)

Answer (score 2):

The following line makes no mention of your `$page_access_token`...

```
$this->post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed';
```

You need something like the following...

```
$this->post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed?access_token='.$this->page_access_token;
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't need to. That is simply the URL to post to. Permissons should be handeled by `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`, where the array `$data` contais the Auth Token. It's hard to tell, as every post I've found is slightly different, but I think the issue may be that I have generated an Auth Token for my App, not for the page that it is to post to (which I don't know how to do). Thanks.

Comment: So you've read the docs and seen all the examples at [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/)? That's probably the best resource, and the most up-to-date. Part of your problem may lie in the fact that they've changed things a number of times. Old examples are rife on the Internets. Can you post your cURL request code..?

Comment: `Old examples are rife on the Internet` - Too true, I've found so many examples that are all slightly different, that it's become a little over whelming! Will revisit all this tomorrow, off home for now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use twitterfeed.com to automatically submit your posts to Facebook with several other options.

Answer (score 0):

The `access_token` you are getting from the Graph API explorer isn't a permanent one. You'll need to refresh it at least every two months, or any time you log out of Facebook.

Rather than code this yourself from scratch, why not use the Facebook PHP SDK? You'll have permanent access to your page using your app's id and secret.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say ditch curl and use the PHP SDK. Assign your site its own app secret etc, and link them to your code.

Now, the next thing you want to ask yourself, is do I want to duplicate the article on facebook, or do I want to link to the article on facebook?

Personally, I would take the link option, in which case you want to post to the LINK stream.

If you post as a link, then it will appear like a proper link post, showing a thumbnail and summary of your post. You can tweak what gets displayed there using OG meta tags.

You can post the entire article instead straight to the feed, but is this really what you want?

This answer is long on theory and short on code. If you need a bit more help be specific as to what you want, based on what I've said above.